What do the Eggman hearts do in Sonic Simulator?
Some of the Sonic Simulator stages in Sonic Colors have pink hearts with Eggman's face on them. What does collecting these hearts with Eggman's face do?

Screenshot from Sonic Colors Wii - [Part 23 - Game Land : Sonic Simulator - Act 1-1 / 1-2 / 1-3 ~ Chaos Emerald 1] by Cyberman65


That's an Egg Medal:

The Egg Medal is a medal in the shape of a flat pink heart, with a golden rim around it and a golden Eggman Empire logo in the middle.
In the Wii version of Sonic Colors there is only one Egg Medal in each Act in the Sonic Simulator. Collecting an Egg Medal awards the player with 50,000 Special Bonus points.

